# Explanation for absolute value

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

So  $f_a:R\rightarrow \:R,\:f_a(x)=\:\frac{1}{\left|x-a\right|+3}$, and we  have to evaluate 
$\lim _{a\to \infty }\int _0^3\:f_a\left(x\right)dx$.

But $\left|x-a\right|\:$ is equal with:

$x-a,\:\:x\in \left[a,\:\infty \right]$

$a-x,\:\:x\in \left(-\infty ,a\right)$

For our limit, I think we need to split: $\int _0^3\:=\:\int _0^a\:\:+\:\int _a^{3\:}\:$?  How we realize how will get the function?

Comment: One may consider 3 cases: $a<0$, $0\le a\le 3$ and $3<a$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your integral, you are only considering values of $x$ in the interval $[0,3]$. Also, you let $a$ tend to infinity, so you can certainly consider only the values of $a$ that are greater than $3$.

Thus, in the expression for $f_a(x)$, you need only consider the case $a>x$, which means that

$$f_a(x) = \frac{1}{(a-x)+3}.$$